# How can I avoid a Cycle error in my module for an RDS instance and security group

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am writing a terraform module that provisions an RDS DB instance, and its associated security group for controlling inbound connections.  The problem I'm running into is that the security group resource requires the DB port as a parameter, and the db instance resource requires the security group ID as a parameter.  Hence the cycle error.

```
resource "aws_security_group" "this" {
  name = "${local.name}-inbound"
  description = "Allow inbound traffic from customer instances and management"
  vpc_id = "${var.vpc_id}"
  ingress {
    from_port = "${aws_db_instance.this.port}"
    to_port   = "${aws_db_instance.this.port}"
    protocol  = 6
    security_groups = ["${var.ingress_sg_ids}"]
  }
}

resource "aws_db_instance" "this" {
  allocated_storage       = "${var.storage_size}"
  storage_type            = "${var.storage_type}"
  engine                  = "${var.db_engine}"
  engine_version          = "${var.db_engine_version}"
  instance_class          = "${var.instance_type}"
  identifier_prefix       = "${local.name}-"
  name                    = "${var.env}_${var.workspace}"
  username                = "${var.root_username}"
  password                = "${random_id.root_password.b64}"
  db_subnet_group_name    = "${aws_db_subnet_group.this.name}"
  parameter_group_name    = "${var.param_group_name}"
  backup_retention_period = "${var.backup_retention_period}"
  copy_tags_to_snapshot   = true
  kms_key_id              = "${aws_kms_key.this.arn}"
  storage_encrypted       = true
  skip_final_snapshot     = "${var.skip_final_snapshot}"
  vpc_security_group_ids  = ["${aws_security_group.this.id}"]
}
```

The error messages is as follows:

```
* Cycle: module.rds.aws_db_instance.this, module.rds.aws_security_group.this
```

Comment: If it's a known DB instance type you can use the default port number without referencing them https://www.cloudconformity.com/conformity-rules/RDS/rds-default-port.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a circular dependency because your instance depends on your security group, whose in-line rule depends on your instance. As a workaround you can use a `aws_security_group_rule` resource:

```
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "db_ingress_sgr" {
  type                     = "ingress"
  security_group_id        = "${aws_security_group.this.id}"
  from_port                = "${aws_db_instance.this.port}"
  to_port                  = "${aws_db_instance.this.port}"
  protocol                 = 6
  source_security_group_id = "${var.ingress_sg_ids}"
}
```

Terraform will create the (empty) Security Group, then your RDS instance, then the Security Group Rule.

**Note** that this way you can only define one `source_security_group_id` at a time, so check the type of your `ingress_sg_ids` variable.

**Note** (from [the docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/security_group.html)):

> At this time you cannot use a Security Group with in-line rules in conjunction with any Security Group Rule resources. Doing so will cause a conflict of rule settings and will overwrite rules.

Answer (score -1):

For creating aws_db_instance you are not passing any specific port. So, default port(3306) will be used for creating this instance. So, instead of referring rds instance in security group you can directly use default port (3306)

```
ingress {
    from_port = "3306"
    to_port   = "3306"
    protocol  = 6
    security_groups = ["${var.ingress_sg_ids}"]
}
```

Comment: Since the db_instance resource provides the port number based on what type of db engine you select, I'd rather not hardcode it.